# Mean then mult or mult and then mean

Tags: mean, group-differences

I have a dataset like the following structure:

```
D | S | A1 | A1_qty
-------------------
1 | 1 | 3  | 4
1 | 1 | 2  | 3
1 | 2 | 2  | 4
1 | 2 | 1  | 3
2 | 1 | 1  | 3
2 | 2 | 2  | 3
2 | 3 | 1  | 3
2 | 3 | 1  | 3
2 | 3 | 4  | 1
```

I want to calculate the mean of `A1 * A1_qty` groups (D) and (D, S).
The question is, what is better (i.e., more accurate):

- calculate first the multi of the columns A1 and A1_qty and then the mean per group, or
- first the mean of `A1` and `A_qty` per group and then the `A1_mean * A1_qty_mean`?

And...why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The safer bet is to multiply first, and then calculate the group level means of the product. If `A` and `A1_qty` are uncorrelated (meaning that they have [covariance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance) equal to 0) then the results will be the same, no matter which order you perform the computations in, but this is often not the case (and for your date it definitely isn't, `A` and `A_qty` have a covariance of -.375).